# How to select lots of friends posts from database

Tags: mysql

```php
$stmt  = $conn->prepare( "SELECT 
post_by, 
id, post_preview,  
post_by_fullname, 
post_meta,
 total_likes, 
total_comments,
 total_shares, 
post_date,
 date_time FROM posts_table WHERE post_by IN( SELECT following FROM followers_table WHERE follower='me') AND post_date<? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

My concern is only about this particular line: `IN( SELECT following FROM followers_table WHERE follower='me')`

This code works fine but i'm worried If i'm following about 1000 people, will this code still function properly and fast. Is there limit to result in "IN()"

Comment: When you are concerned about database performance it helps us to see the declarations of the tables involved as well as the query itself. We review code to help you improve your coding skills, we don't answer how to questions. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) as it says:

> The number of values in the IN() list is only limited by the
> [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)
> value.

So that limits the number of friends you can use here. The default value is 67108864, so I wouldn't worry.

In my experience using `IN()` is always quite fast. They also say how it works:

> The values the list are sorted and the search ... is done using a
> binary search, which makes the IN() operation very quick.

It basically works like a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM values WHERE value = searched
```

In your query however, the use doesn't seem appropriate. It looks like you could simply use a table join, like this:

```
SELECT 
  P.*
FROM 
  posts_table AS P
INNER JOIN 
  followers_table AS F ON P.post_by = F.following
WHERE 
  F.follower = 'me' AND P.post_date < ? 
ORDER BY 
  P.id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I've got no way to test this, so I cannot be sure it is correct, but something like this seems more sensible to me. You're basically trying to get a result by combining the data from 2 tables and a join is the normal way of doing that.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading this right, but I don't think the OP is wanting to build a dynamic IN clause. He/she seems to be more concerned about the *number of records* in the table `followers_table`, that is used for the subselect. The answer is that more records could potentially lead to higher execution times but it boils down to **table structure**, presence of **indexes** etc. The other WHERE criteria can cause a slowdown too, for instance if post_date is not covered by an index. The subselect is not necessarily the biggest bottleneck.

Comment: To clarify, the `max_allowed_packet` value would be relevant if you were building a large concatenated string for your IN clause (lots of comma-separated values).

Comment: @Kate No, you're reading it correctly. I therefore first answered the question about the _number of records_, and only then suggested another structure for the query. You are probably right that the subselect isn't more inefficient than the join. I don't know whether `max_allowed_packet` is only relevant for a concatenated string. It's unlikely. For instance; `IN()` works with multiple strings, not just one. I think [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) implies that any data in `IN()` is limited by `max_allowed_packet` bytes.